# IPB where edit navigation links?

Tags: ipb

I want to edit navigation links, but I dont know where. Where i should go in admin menu to edit navigation links or in which file at ftp? I looked almost everythere in administration panel, but couldn't find anything...

IPB version 3.4.5

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about website administration.

Answer (score 0):

Each module for IPB has it's own navigation style index file located in your styles panel of the ACP. Each categaroy should have a root in the Index group.